# Sorting Array of objects into alphabetical order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of Entries in a phone book. Each Entry object has three fields. Surname, initial and number. I want to sort the phone book array alphabetically by surname. I'm not sure the best way to do it. I'm trying to use the compareTo method for strings, but im not sure the best way to swap the Entries around if one surname is White and the other is Smith for example. I have some code which I thought would compare the Entry I'm adding to the phone book with the Entry immediately before it in the array as long as its not the first Entry being added to the phone book. But it doesn't seem to be having any affect on the array at all.

```
 public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{

String surname;
String initial;
String number;


public Entry(String surname, String initial, String number) {
    this.surname = surname;
    this.initial = initial;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getSurname(){
    return surname;
}

public String getInitial(){
    return initial;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

void setNumber(String number){
    this.number = number;
}

public String toString(){
    return surname+ "\t " +initial+ "\t" +number;
}


public int compareTo(Entry e) {
    return this.surname.compareToIgnoreCase(e.surname);
}


}


 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory{


private int DIRECTORY_SIZE = 6; 
Entry [] directory = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE];
private int numberOfElements = 0;

public int getNumOfElements(){
    return numberOfElements;
}

public void setDirectorySize(int size){
    DIRECTORY_SIZE = size;
}

public int getDirectorySize(){
    return DIRECTORY_SIZE;
}




public void addEntry(String surname, String initial, String num) {
    // TODO add an entry to an array, also increments numberOfElements variable tracking whats in array 

    if(getNumOfElements() == getDirectorySize()){    // if array is full
        doubleArraySize();     // put temp values into new bigger directory array
    }

    int i = findFreeLocation();     

    directory[i] = new Entry(surname, initial, num);

    if( i > 0 ){

        if(directory[i-1].compareTo(directory[i]) == 1){

            Entry[] temp = new Entry[1];
            temp[0] = directory[i-1];
            directory[i-1] = directory[i];
            directory[i] = temp[0];
        }

    }
    numberOfElements++;
}
```

Comment: Use a `TreeSet<Entry>` and either implement `Comparable<Entry>` or pass a `Comparator<Entry>` into your `TreeSet`. Ensure that the comparison method compares on all fields so that you don't remove duplicated unnecessarily. A `TreeSet` guarantees that elements within are always sorted according to the comparator.

Comment: I'm going to use a few data structures but the first one I will try it with is an Array. I'm making implementations for linked list and hashset to, but I need to make it work with arrays first

Comment: I've implemented a compareTo method and I've used Arrays.sort(directory) however I'm getting exceptions. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Entry.compareTo(Entry.java:37)
 at Entry.compareTo(Entry.java:1)
 at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
 at ArrayDirectory.addEntry(ArrayDirectory.java:36)
 at Test.main(Test.java:10). Any idea why?

Comment: The only reason why it can throw a `NullPointerException` there is that the surname of one entry is `null`. You have to avoid this case, or treat it appropriately. Also note that using a `TreeSet` may have undesirable results here: A `TreeSet` may contain each element only once, and your `compareTo` method must be *consistent with equals* (according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html ) to make sure that the `TreeSet` works properly.